# Restrict Invoice Release if condition satisfied and custom error thrown

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have override Invoices screen Release action to restrict the Invoice release if my condition satisfied and the custom error is thrown, but even the error is thrown and after closing that error, the Invoice still gets released but I want to restrict the Invoice release if error is thrown.

```
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter)
    {            
        if (Base.Document.Current != null)
        {
            var paymentSetup = PaySetup.SelectSingle(Base.Document.Current.PaymentMethodID);
            var paymentSettings = PaySettingDetails.SelectSingle(Base.Document.Current.PaymentMethodID);

            if (paymentSettings != null && paymentSetup != null && paymentSetup.IsActive == true)
            {
                if (this.PayCurrentInvoice.Current != null && this.PayCurrentInvoice.Current.PayStatus.ToUpper() != KNPIConstants.PAID)
                {
                    throw new PXException(KNPIMessages.NotPaid);
                }
            }                  
            else
            {
                return Base.release.Press(adapter);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The Invoice should not gets released if the error is thrown but even though the error is throwing, after closing that error still the Invoice gets released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your override is wrong!

```
 public delegate IEnumerable ReleaseDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
 [PXOverride]
 public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter, ReleaseDelegate baseMethod)
  {
      var paymentSetup = PaySetup.SelectSingle(Base.Document.Current.PaymentMethodID);
      var paymentSettings = PaySettingDetails.SelectSingle(Base.Document.Current.PaymentMethodID);

      if (paymentSettings != null && paymentSetup != null && paymentSetup.IsActive == true)
      {
          if (this.PayCurrentInvoice.Current != null && this.PayCurrentInvoice.Current.PayStatus.ToUpper() != KNPIConstants.PAID)
          {
              throw new PXException(KNPIMessages.NotPaid);
          }
      }
      return baseMethod(adapter);
  }
```